# Kill a process in Ubuntu by name

Tags: ubuntu, kill

I got this process with changing id:

```
/var/www/default/dn# ps aux | grep 'solr'
root     11060  0.0  0.0   9680   940 pts/0    S+   03:52   0:00 grep --color=auto solr
/var/www/default/dn# ps aux | grep 'solr'
root     11090  0.0  0.0   9680   940 pts/0    S+   03:53   0:00 grep --color=auto solr
```

Is there any way to kill the process by ''name''?

Comment: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_killall.htm

Comment: There is no process named `solr` (from the output that you show).  So there is nothing to kill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not the processes you're looking for.

You're seeing `grep`, that's why the id changes.  Each call is a separate invocation.